# select json_object() into list postgres function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Here i am trying to get all the select values in a varible.

```
 DECLARE
   ite json;
 BEGIN   
   select INTO ite from json_object('{1}','{1}');    
 RETURN ite;
```

when i call this function i got the result null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SELECT INTO in [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html).

**SELECT INTO**: define a new table from the results of a query

**Synopsis**

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT [ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ] ]
    * | expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...]
    INTO [ TEMPORARY | TEMP | UNLOGGED ] [ TABLE ] new_table
    [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition ]
    [ GROUP BY expression [, ...] ]
    [ HAVING condition [, ...] ]
    [ WINDOW window_name AS ( window_definition ) [, ...] ]
    [ { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT } [ ALL | DISTINCT ] select ]
    [ ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC | USING operator ] [ NULLS { FIRST | LAST } ] [, ...] ]
    [ LIMIT { count | ALL } ]
    [ OFFSET start [ ROW | ROWS ] ]
    [ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ count ] { ROW | ROWS } ONLY ]
    [ FOR { UPDATE | SHARE } [ OF table_name [, ...] ] [ NOWAIT ] [...] ]
```

**Examples**

Create a new table films_recent consisting of only recent entries from the table films:

```
SELECT * INTO films_recent FROM films WHERE date_prod >= '2002-01-01';
```

---

Try the next syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_json()
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
   ite text;
BEGIN   
   select * into ite from json_object('{1}','{1}');
   return ite;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ```
> select * from fn_get_json();
> ```
>
> ```
> | fn_get_json |
> | :---------- |
> | {"1" : "1"} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=856faa30a4f5630896c1324085761ee1)*

Or as pointed out in comments a reduced version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_json()
RETURNS json AS
$$
BEGIN   
   return json_object('{1}','{1}');
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or even simpler with a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_json()
RETURNS json AS
$$
   select json_object('{1}','{1}');
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

> select values in a varible

I think what you want here is a [`jsonb_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) which aggregates values as a JSON array.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(foo)
FROM ( VALUES (1,2,'foo'), (2,3,'bar') ) AS foo(a,b,c);
                          jsonb_agg                           
--------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "foo"}, {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": "bar"}]
```

There is also `jsonb_object_agg(name, value)`

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(a,b)
FROM ( VALUES ('key1','value1'),('key2','value2') ) AS t(a,b);
           jsonb_object_agg           
--------------------------------------
 {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Though I admit it's somewhat hard to tell you've provided so little.